# PHP implode() error on hosted website and works on localhost

Tags: php, prestashop, implode

I have an odd problem with a PrestaShop 1.6.x module and the PHP `implode()` function. On localhost I do not get any exceptions when I run the query. However, on the hosted web store I get the following exception:

> Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in ../WineSpecifications.php on line 183

And all the lines that use the `implode()`.

Further on, all the data from the input fields is getting saved in the DB and after refresh it is all there.

My question is why do I get the error only on the hosted web store? And also how do I get rid of it?

This is the part of the query that causes the problem:

```
      if ($this->existProduct('product_specification_lang', $id_product)) {
        foreach ($languages as $lang) {
            $multiLangQuery .= 'UPDATE '._DB_PREFIX_."product_specification_lang SET
                region='".pSQL(Tools::getValue('region_'.$lang['id_lang']))."',
                wine_type='".pSQL(Tools::getValue('wine_type_'.$lang['id_lang']))."',
                food_pairings='".pSQL(implode(', ', Tools::getValue('food_pairings_'.$lang['id_lang'])))."',
                tastes='".pSQL(implode(', ', Tools::getValue('tastes_'.$lang['id_lang'])))."',
                scents='".pSQL(implode(', ', Tools::getValue('scents_'.$lang['id_lang'])))."',
                varietal_blend='".pSQL(Tools::getValue('varietal_blend_'.$lang['id_lang']))."',
                composition='".pSQL(Tools::getValue('composition_'.$lang['id_lang']))."',
                vineyard='".pSQL(Tools::getValue('vineyard_'.$lang['id_lang']))."',
                aging_program='".pSQL(Tools::getValue('aging_program_'.$lang['id_lang']))."',
                oak_origin='".pSQL(Tools::getValue('oak_origin_'.$lang['id_lang']))."',
                barrel_toast='".pSQL(Tools::getValue('barrel_toast_'.$lang['id_lang']))."',
                barrel_head_toast='".pSQL(Tools::getValue('barrel_head_toast_'.$lang['id_lang']))."',
                wine_sweetness='".pSQL(Tools::getValue('wine_sweetness_'.$lang['id_lang']))."',
                container_type='".pSQL(Tools::getValue('container_type_'.$lang['id_lang']))."',
                bottle_material='".pSQL(Tools::getValue('bottle_material_'.$lang['id_lang']))."',
                bottle_color='".pSQL(Tools::getValue('bottle_color_'.$lang['id_lang']))."',
                closure_type='".pSQL(Tools::getValue('closure_type_'.$lang['id_lang']))."',
                closure_material='".pSQL(Tools::getValue('closure_material_'.$lang['id_lang']))."',
                special_version='".pSQL(Tools::getValue('special_version_'.$lang['id_lang']))."',
                case_production='".pSQL(Tools::getValue('case_production_'.$lang['id_lang']))."',
                special_features='".pSQL(Tools::getValue('special_features_'.$lang['id_lang']))."',
                winery='".pSQL(Tools::getValue('winery_'.$lang['id_lang']))."',
                winemaker='".pSQL(Tools::getValue('winemaker_'.$lang['id_lang']))."',
                three_word_taste_summary='".pSQL(Tools::getValue('three_word_taste_summary_'.$lang['id_lang']))."',
                tasting_notes='".pSQL(Tools::getValue('tasting_notes_'.$lang['id_lang']))."',
                vintage_notes='".pSQL(Tools::getValue('vintage_notes_'.$lang['id_lang']))."',
        sweet_or_dry='".pSQL(Tools::getValue('sweet_or_dry_'.$lang['id_lang']))."'
                WHERE id_product=".$id_product.' AND id_lang = '.$lang['id_lang'].' ; ';
        }
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you confirmed that the second parameter is an array? Why don't you try `food_pairings='".pSQL(implode(', ', (array)Tools::getValue('food_pairings_'.$lang['id_lang'])))."',`?

Comment: `Tools::getValue()` isn't returning an array and you have error reporting disabled on your localhost.